# Schrodinger equation in momentum space- How to make it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

> Use the Schrodinger equation in momentum space to analyze bound states of a particle in the potential, $U(x)=α[δ(x-a)+δ(x+a)]$.

I'm a student in a university and I'm learning about Schrödinger's equation. I wonder how to get it in momentum space. The hint of this problem show that:
[image]

I would like to ask that how to get a result for U(p) and take the form of the schrodinger in momentum space like the hint. I really need your help!!

Comment: fourier transform

Comment: [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential#Double_delta_potential)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos the solution you link is in x-space and is indeed straightforward.  If you have a link to p-space solution for finitely many wells please *do* share.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero. Well, the Fourier transforms of exponentials of absolute values are Lorentzians (Cauchy distributions), so, unless one were prepared to pile up garlands of convolutions of such, I'd stick with the straightforward Scott et al. elegant answer originally steered to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give a hand which should elucidate how to solve the problem. Recall the Schrodinger equation is

$$\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x)\right)\psi(x) = E\psi(x).$$

The Fourier transformed wave function $\tilde{\psi}(p)$ is given by,

$$\tilde{\psi}(p)=\int dx \, e^{-ipx}\psi(x).$$

In finding the momentum space version of the equation, we have to compute the integral,

$$\mathcal{F}\{V(x)\psi(x)\} = \alpha \int dx \, e^{-ipx}\left[ \delta(x-a) + \delta(x+a)\right]\psi(x)=\alpha(\psi(a)e^{-ipa}+\psi(-a)e^{ipa})$$

using the rules of integrating delta functions. We thus arrive at,

$$\frac{\hbar^2p^2}{2m}\tilde{\psi}(p) + \alpha(\psi(a)e^{-ipa}+\psi(-a)e^{ipa}) = E\tilde{\psi}(p).$$

Comment: This is totally correct but doesn't seem to help much in eventually concluding there are two bound states...or am I just too tired to see the obvious...

Comment: @Zero that's an algebraic equation for the momentum-space wavefunction that's easily solvable, after which you just need to transform back and check the normalizability.

Comment: @JamalS Dear Jamals, actually, it have more problems that I really  dont know exactly, I want to ask you some question about this issue, could you give me your email!!

Comment: @NamHồ Use the chatroom on this site.

Comment: @JamalS I have just edit my question to provide exactly more about my issue ( I dont understand why the result like that- how to make it). Please considers the hint of this problem, And if possible, please help me explain that how to get a result like that. Thank you so much!!!!.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the equation, and do a Fourier Transform on that.

Say (for simplicity) in 1-D, we have,
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(x)=(E-V(x))\psi(x)$$
Now you can express the wave function in terms of its Fourier Transform,
$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int dk e^{-ikx}\,\tilde{\psi}(k)$$
and similarly for the potential $V(x)$. Plug these into the Schrödinger equation, and you can work out the equation in momentum representation.

Comment: Not quite. You then need to do an inverse transform, or you won't be able to extract anything useful.

Comment: I agree. That is after solving and getting the momentum space solution.